# JQUERY draggable and on functions

Tags: jquery

I want to use the jQuery draggable function for the first time.
I use this guide for that:

http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/

Actually everything is clear but I don't know which API I could use.
For jQuery I generally use the google API for the latest version:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But for the draggable function I need these two libraries:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

The second one isn't a problem because it includes only the functions like `draggable`. But, I believe, this first one includes jQuery again. The result is that the function `on` is unknown. I use `on` like this:

```
$('.1234').on('click', function () {...})
```

So I tried some alternatives. If I include the first instead of the second one the draggable event doesn't work. The initialize works but if I want to drag the DOM element I get a lot of errors in my console from the code which I included by url. If I include the second instead of the first one the console tells me that on() is unknown.

Does someone know which url I have to use to use jQuery with on() and draggable()?

Comment: Why are you load jQuery again (and a really old version, too)? It overwrites the first jQuery instance, and makes [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) unavailable because it is only available at a later version. The reason why draggable doesn't work when you load the first one is probably because of a typo, or version incompatibility. Just load both jQuery and jQuery UI from Google CDN, that will be fine. p/s: It's **draggable** with two g's.

Comment: @Terry thank you for your fast answer. i expected that the second include overwrite the first one. Now i use the newest version from Google CDN. I hoped i can use dynamically the newest version. But doesnt matter. Now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your approach:

1. You are using a very outdated version of jQuery. If you want to stick to using v1, use v1.12 instead. `.on()` is not available until version 1.7 onwards.
2. You are loading jQuery twice. Load it once, otherwise you risk masking it with a legacy version.
3. Draggable is spelled with two g's.

If you load the latest version of [jQuery v1.x](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery) and [jQuery UI](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery-ui), it works. See proof-of-concept below:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.draggable')
  .draggable()
  .on('drag', function() {
    console.log('dragged');
  })
  .on('click', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="draggable">Draggable</div>
```